# Target Unreachable, identifier resolved to null

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a problem with a simple web application in JSF 2.2, my managed bean is not solved and I got this error:

```
 /greeting.xhtml @21,66 date="#{dukesBDay.yourBD}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'dukesBDay' resolved to null
```

This is my managed bean:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DukesBDay {


@EJB
private DukesBirthDayBean dukesBirthdayBean;
```

This is my greeting.xhtml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:fc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">

<h:head>
    <title>First Cup Greeting Page</title>
</h:head>

<h:form>
<h2>
    <h:outputText value="#{bundle.Welcome}"/>
</h2>
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.DukeIs} "/>
<h:outputText value="#{dukesBDay.age} #{bundle.YearsOldToday}"/>
<p/>
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.Instructions}"/>
<p/>
<h:outputText value="#{bundle.YourBD} "/>
<fc:inputDate id="userBirthday" date="#{dukesBDay.yourBD}" />
<h:outputText value=" #{bundle.Pattern}"/>
<p/>
<h:commandButton value="#{bundle.Submit}" 
                 action="#{dukesBDay.processBirthday}"/>
<p/>
<h:message for="userBirthday" style="color:red"/>
</h:form>
```

and this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>    
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>greeting.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I tried adding the name property to @ManagedBean:

```
package firstcup.web;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
@ManagedBean(name="dukesBDay")
@SessionScoped
public class DukesBDay {
```

but it doesn't work, still have the same error.

I tried mapping the managed bean in my faces-config:

```
 <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>dukesBDay</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>firstcup.web.DukesBDay</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
```

but I get this error:

> Unable to create managed bean dukesBDay. The following problems were found: - Bean or property class firstcup.web.DukesBDay for managed bean dukesBDay cannot be found

Why my DukesBDay is not solved? What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: No obvious symptoms are found. The problem might be associated with the composite component. Did you also map the managed bean in the JSF configuration file `faces.config.xml` file? Are you interested in designing XHTML files without using an `<h:body>` tag?

Comment: No, I didn't map the managed bean in faces.config.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved restarting NetBeans and GlassFish Server.

I didn't add the name property to @ManagedBean:

```
package firstcup.web;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DukesBDay {
```

and everything works, so it isn't necessary (according to naming convention, you can refer to the bean using the uncapitalized short name of the Class)

Answer (score 0):

when you write @ManagedBean, you should also add the name property to that.

```
@ManagedBean(name="dukesBDay")
@sessionscoped
```

the other way to declare your managed bean is, using faceconfig.xml file.

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>dukesBDay</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>package.DukesBDay</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>
```

If you don't specify dukesBDay along with @ManagedBean, it will be resolved to null.

Comment: I tried adding the name property to @ManagedBean, but it doesn't work.